# Why is it recommended to return with the `error` interface in go rather than with the concrete error type?

Tags: go, struct, error-handling, interface

The go FQA [states](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error):

> It's a good idea for functions that return errors always to use the error type in their signature (as we did above) rather than a concrete type such as *MyError, to help guarantee the error is created correctly. As an example, [os.Open](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) returns an error even though, if not nil, it's always of concrete type [*os.PathError](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#PathError).

But [this article](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) claims that sometimes it is OK to return with a concrete type:

> (It's usually a mistake to pass back the concrete type of an error rather than error, for reasons discussed in the Go FAQ, but it's the right thing to do here because `ServeHTTP` is the only place that sees the value and uses its contents.)

My question is, what are the benefits of returning with `error` rather than the concrete type, how does it help guarantee that the error is created correctly, and why is it okay to return the concrete type when the error is not used in different places?

Comment: not sure why it gets downvoted but i think it's a valid question. this video might provide more explanation. https://youtu.be/ynoY2xz-F8s?t=897

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to `error` being an interface. An interface contains a pointer to the value it contains and the type of that value. An interface is nil only if both of those values are nil. So, if you return a concrete error type from a function, and then return an `error`, that error will not be nil.

[live on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Q0xdQc-CJJK)

```
type MyError string

func (e MyError) Error() string {return string(e)}

func f() *MyError {
  return nil
}

func g() error {
  return f()
}


func main() {
  x:=g()
  if x==nil {
    fmt.Println("nil")
  }
}
```

In the example above, even though `*MyError` value is nil, the return value of `g()` is not, because it contains an interface with type `*MyError` and value nil.

This is a problem for all functions returning an interface value, and most commonly observed with `error` types. So do not declare functions returning concrete error values unless those functions have very limited use, such as unexported functions.

Comment: The same exact reasoning can be applied to never return an interface. Your example shows just that.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik, it does not showt hat, and there are perfectly legitimate uses of returning interfaces.

Comment: It does. Normally you reuse code from other packages, thus you have no control over the contents of the returned interface object. It is **merely impossible** to reliably check for `nil` in that case. And this kind of bug will be very hard to catch without debugger. nillable interfaces in GO, where `nil` may have a type and be not same as `nil` is an awful side effect of an ugly reflection implementation.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik, most factory pattern implementations return interfaces (db drivers is one example). Using tuples `func f() (someIntf,error)` instead of nil interfaces with the rule that only one of them is non-nil, and this becomes an easy problem to deal with.

Comment: well, just imagine that your `g()` is now `func g() *SomeObj, error` a factory of a third-party package. Good luck checking for `err == nil`. Your example shows exactly how it wouldn't work.